# Hide console of phantomJS driver

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, cx-freeze

I'm using phantomJS driver (in python 3.3). I initialize it by

`self._phantom = webdriver.PhantomJS('path/to/phantomJS.exe')`

And this is OK, console doesn't appear. But when I build the project using cx_freeze to exe file, then the console does appear.

It's not much a problem, but my program opens about 3 windows and dialogs, and another windows (especially console) might be too confusing or distracting for customer.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: When you're freezing the application, you can choose a 'base'. If you choose the 'Console' base on Windows, it will always open a console. If you choose the `Win32GUI` base, it won't (thought selenium or phantom may open a console themselves).

Comment: Thomas K: I have this option, so I guess selenium opens the console itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran in the same problem and I was able to fix it by patching the selenium python module.

This is the file, I've submitted a patch to the selenium github
https://github.com/Lazik/selenium/blob/d790915a1124bd4730f10855c7e0a40ab6e6b59f/py/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py

Overwrite the service.py file you can find it in 
your python_install folder\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common 
Mine is here:
C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your service.py also works with Python 2.7, after downloading the appropriate pypiwin32 module from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32/219

Comment: new method here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639052/pyinstaller-one-file-no-console-does-not-work-fatal-error