# pyinstaller one file --no-console does not work "Fatal Error"

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller

I try 2 options with pyinstaller one with console and one without.

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.5.4, Windows Chrome Driver 2.33 and Selnium 3.6.0 and Pyinstaller 3.3.

The one ***without*** console fails:

Here is the code for ***Test.py***

```
#!python3
from selenium import webdriver

# Chrome Proxy options and disable the Yellow Bar about Chrome being controlled by Automated Software.
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-default-apps")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")


# load google.com with the proxy settings and a logging path to a file
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)

# maximise window
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.google.com/mail")
```

Here are the pyinstaller commands with the exact same code:

*- With console window aka works:*

```
pyinstaller -F -i favicon.ico Test.py
```

*- Without the console Window fails*

```
pyinstaller -F --noconsole -i favicon.ico Test.py
```

I get this error:

```
*"Failed to execute script error"*
```

I am not sure why.

Thanks

---

Thanks for your reply I looked in:

```
C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\service.py
```

There was nothing for subprocess here.

I also checked:

```
C:\Users\testuer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py
```

On line 70 I added in the entry for stdin=self.log_file as it was missing

```
 try:
            cmd = [self.path]
            cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                            close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                            stdin=self.log_file, stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
```

Recreated with pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller -F --noconsole  -i favicon.ico Test.py
```

This created the exe however now the console window appeared....

[Python program with selenium(webdriver) Don't Work as single and noconsole exe file (pyinstaller)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867183/python-program-with-seleniumwebdriver-dont-work-as-single-and-noconsole-exe-f)

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867183/python-program-with-seleniumwebdriver-dont-work-as-single-and-noconsole-exe-f Seems to be on the topic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after some search I found the full solution :
Firstly go to -

```
C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py
```

Change :

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                            close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                            stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
```

To:

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False, creationflags=0x08000000)
```

now simply build your app.py like this:

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile  --noupx   Yourfile.py
```

Comment: your answer its right, but you remain with chromedrivers open running on task manager, is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly go to-
`C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py`

then in `def start(self):`

`def start(self):`
 `""" Starts the Service.`

```
    :Exceptions:
     - WebDriverException : Raised either when it can't start the service
       or when it can't connect to the service
    """
    try:
        cmd = [self.path]
        cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                        close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                        stdout=self.log_file,
                                        stderr=self.log_file,
                                        stdin=PIPE,
                                        creationflags=0x08000000)``
```

Just add **creationflags=0x08000000** , I've already added there in the code.
creationflags is a constant. It will work fine.

or,
you might also replace it with `creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW` and add this line code `from win32process import CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.

In my case, first method was working.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone:

C:\Users\%user_name%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common

Add import and change in "def start":

from win32process import CREATE_NO_WINDOW

```
    try:
        cmd = [self.path]
        cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                        close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                        stdin=self.log_file, stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
    except TypeError:
        raise
```

if error, check pywin32:
pip install pywin32