# After doing pyinstaller --noconsole , phantomjs.exe console appear when running the program

Tags: process, phantomjs, pyinstaller

I am doing a final project in a python course and I have done a program using phantomjs that run like a background process in windows.

Therefore, after creating my project, I used pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile to my file in order to hide his console but even tough I did it, I still get a console popup - phantomjs.exe 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Zx8.png)

Someone know how to remove the console without impairing the proper functioning of the program.

Thanks alot,

Omer

**Note:** in my spec file in the exe option there is debug = False!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by editing the service.py file in selenium folder (C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py)

Just look at here: [pyinstaller one file --no-console does not work "Fatal Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639052/pyinstaller-one-file-no-console-does-not-work-fatal-error)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you need to set your python env to python executable without window/console for example make sure you select your python.exe and NOT pythonw.exe as in attachment below. The reason for that is because pythonw.exe will import selenium/webdriver in turn call phantomjs.exe to be executed and open a terminal console

[image]