# Pyinstaller - failed to execute script when code includes Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, windows-10, pyinstaller, python-3.7

My .exe file does not run when my code includes Selenium - webdriver.

Here is my code (i named my script test.py):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://google.com/"
driver.get(url)
```

Then i run this on Powershell:

```
pyinstaller test.py
```

or this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed test.py
```

But when i try to run the test.exe file, i am getting the failed to execute script error.

I am on Win 10, Python 3.7 and latest PyInstaller (3.5).

I tried this solution:

[pyinstaller one file --no-console does not work "Fatal Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639052/pyinstaller-one-file-no-console-does-not-work-fatal-error)

but it didn't work. Note that when i use pyinstaller with a code that does not include Selenium, everything is fine so far.

Can you please advise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are getting this **error** because your script can't find gecko driver to execute script so you need to paste geckodriver in your file directory

Comment: Most Welcome! have a nice day