# Pyinstaller noconsole option makes exe fatal error [Solved]

Tags: pyinstaller

hi I am very new to programming. 
I made sciprt with Anaconda virtual environment and

python 3.5.6, pyinstaller 3.5, selenium 3.141, pyqt5 5.13.2, pymysql 0.9.3

it works fine in atom. 
and also works fine when I do

```
pyinstaller --onefile myapp.py
```

but when I do

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile myapp.py
```

in command prompt it says completed successfully. 
but when I click myapp.exe,
fatal error massage box show up. like below

```
fatal error detected

failed to execute script MyScript
```

I searched alot, but couldn't find why.

---

I did some work as https://stackoverflow.com/a/47229908/12471379
still don't know how to fix.

---

01.07.20

now I got nothing, not even devTool thing from cmd when I run myapp.exe

which made by `pyinstaller --onefile myapp.py`

still don't work with --noconsole

---

01.08.20

I just make new venv, did

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile --noupx myapp.py
```

only warning I got is

```
23142 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
23352 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
```

but since it's only warning. I ignore this.
and don't work
getting crazy....

---

01.09.20
problem solved.

I was so stupid.... I believe this happen because I am very new to programming
I will leave this so no beginner would make same mistake as me.

if you are not native English speaker.
you might have some unicode changing in your script.
like this

```
import sys
import io
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stderr.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
```

I just copy and paste this from my lecture video. so didn't know nothing about this. and still don't know. I think this translate error to my language.

problem was this part.

```
import io
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stderr.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
```

don't know exactly why.
I just erase it. and change servier.py as https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118530/12471379

than do `pyinstaller --clean --noconsole --onefile --noupx myapp.py`

works!!!

I know this is so basic mistake. 
but I hope this might help some beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your issue was related to the reconfiguration of the encoding of the system standard output and standard error `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`.

If you still want to change the encoding of `stdout` and `stderr`, the following code should works (without stopping you to use `pyinstaller` with the `--noconsole` option):

```py
import codecs
if sys.stdout.encoding != 'UTF-8':
    sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout.buffer, 'strict')
if sys.stderr.encoding != 'UTF-8':
    sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stderr.buffer, 'strict')
```